# Using dask performance report with concurrent.future

Tags: dask-distributed, concurrent.futures

I have a workflow that runs with dask and/or with concurrent.futures. Basically, depending on the machine that the code runs, it runs on dask or with the futures executor. Now, inside my code I am using the performance report from dask, like:

```
from dask.distributed import performance_report

executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() if args.futures else dask.compute()  #### this is a simplification of the actual executor.

with performance_report(filename="dask-report.html"):
   executor(job)
```

Now, in the way that my code (successfully) runs, even if the executor is with futures, I get a performance report from Dask.

My question is, is this performance report doing/measuring something? Again, when opening the HTML file, I see some performance plots for CPU and memory, which I would like to know if they are accurate.

thanks